# Trying to use a variable in a json file path - javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to use a variable to access a field in my json file,
how do I do something like this?
js:

```js
let file = require('./file.json')
let someVar = 'firstField'
console.log(file.firstObject.{someVar})
```

json:

```json
{
  "firstObject": {
     "firstField":"firstValue",
     "secondField":"secondValue",
     "thirdField":"thirdValue",
  },
  "otherObject": {
     "otherField":"otherValue"
  }
}
```

desired outcome :

```
'firstValue'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object[str]` is what you are looking for.
Your code should look like this:

```js
let file = require('./file.json')
let someVar = 'firstField'
console.log(file.firstObject[someVar])
```